# default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true) what is it?

Tags: java, android

I am write a time tracking app and in logcat very often a can see:

```
2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:02:25.140    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:02:40.192    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:02:53.216    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:02:54.128    3575-3575/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1094K, 19% free 6781K/8288K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
05-04 04:02:55.468    3575-3575/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-04 04:02:56.524    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:03:08.504    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:03:19.584    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:03:23.792        65-65/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
05-04 04:03:23.792        65-65/? D/Genymotion﹕ Received Set Clipboard
05-04 04:03:30.576    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:03:40.571    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:03:45.371        65-65/? D/Genyd﹕ Received Set Clipboard
05-04 04:03:45.371        65-65/? D/Genymotion﹕ Received Set Clipboard
05-04 04:03:48.575    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:03:58.599    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:04:08.691    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:04:11.659    3575-3575/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1094K, 19% free 6781K/8288K, paused 10ms, total 11ms
05-04 04:04:12.895    2028-2070/? D/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
05-04 04:04:13.255    3575-3575/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I have the listview with timers with separate thread on each row. Counting occurs in separate thread, they are sending empty messages to handler(just for activated him).
Here is there fragment of code from my model:

```
private String name;
private  Boolean isStart=false, isFinished=false;
private Long elapsedTime=0L,seconds=0L,hours=0L,minutes=0L,lastPause=0L,updateTime=0L,startTime=0L,days=0L,limitTime=0L;
class TrackerThread extends Thread{
    public TrackerThread() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        try {
            while (isStart){
            if (isStart && startTime != 0) {
                if (elapsedTime != 0 && updateTime == 0)
                    lastPause = elapsedTime;
                updateTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + lastPause);
                seconds = updateTime / 1000;
                minutes = seconds / 60;
                hours = minutes / 60;

                seconds = seconds % 60;
                minutes = minutes % 60;
                hours = hours % 24;

                elapsedTime = updateTime;
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                sleep(1000);

            }
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        holder.days.setText(String.format("%04d", days));
            holder.hours.setText(String.format("%02d", hours));
            holder.minutes.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes));
            holder.seconds.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds));

        if(limitTime!=0 && elapsedTime>limitTime) {
            isFinished = true;
            holder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.textFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.limDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.limMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.limHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            RemindMe.db.execSQL(Util.concat("UPDATE trackers SET isFinish=1, elapsedTime=",limitTime," WHERE _id=",getId()));
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```